# is smart contract excution in every node give the same result?

Tags: go-ethereum

In Ethereum as I know that every full node executes the transaction of the contract, hence if there is a code as follows:

```
f() { 
   string x; 
   if(time()<12) 
       x=AM 
   else 
      x=PM
}
```

So if a transaction arrived to a node before 12 and to another node after 12 does that mean that the valuse of x is diffrent depending on the node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ethereum, like all blockchains, are fully deterministic and all smart contract executions give the same results on all nodes.

In this case `time()` or `now` (alias for `block.timestamp`) as it is called in Solidity is the timestamp of the block when it was mined.

This is set by the miner. By the network rules it can vary +-3 minutes of the UTC time the other network nodes have, or nodes will reject the new block.

So when the smart contract refers to the `now`, the time is actually the timestamp when the block where the transaction was included was mined.

Comment: Should we also consider `blockhash(n)` since block hash can be influenced by miners to some degree.